# CLI RPI: How to fdisk and defrag your flashdisk

Tags: raspberry-pi, repair, defragmentation

Hey does anoybody knows a site or command to fdisk your flashcard on your raspberry? Secondly i want to defrag it.

Anybody help? Greets, Wouter

[PS: It is mounted in this enclosure. You can always ask for further explanation of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRkxm.jpg)

Comment: Hi Wouter. This is more of a configuration question than a coding question. As such I think you're likelier to get it answered in [raspberrypi stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/). Good luck!

Comment: To see how to defrag try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221079/how-to-defrag-an-ext4-filesystem), but take into account that defraging EXT4 is usually useless. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: And as for flashing a flash card look at the [raspberry pi imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-imager-imaging-utility/).